# How to set "default" .bash_profile when opening Terminal on Catalina

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, zsh

I'm running Catalina, 10.15.2, which uses the new zsh shell as a default. I've created my own .bash_profile file in my home directory and I'm able to initialize this .bash_profile by typing:

```
source .bash_profile
```

The problem is that I have to keep typing "source ..." each time I open a new terminal shell. How do I default the shell to always use this .bash_profile file? Thanks!

Comment: The default zsh config files are .zprofile/.zshrc. If **your** .bash_profile works with zsh you can simply rename it to .zprofile if no older/other .zprofile exists already... - In my env I sourced .zprofile in .zshrc.

Answer (score 6):

`zsh` uses different config files, see the 'STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES' section in `man zsh`. You can run one of

```
mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.zprofile
mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.zshrc
```

to rename the file, see the man page or https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050 for the difference between these:

> If you're using a bash profile, such as to set environment variables, aliases, or path variables, you should switch to using a zsh equivalent. For example:
>
> - .zprofile is equivalent to .bash_profile and runs at login, including over SSH
> - .zshrc is equivalent to .bashrc and runs for each new Terminal session

Comment: Thank you Sir!  This should be part of the official Apple Docs!

Comment: @vgoklani That's what `man zsh` is for, or https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050

Answer (score 1):

You can also just add `source .bash_profile` at the bottom of your `~/.zshrc` file